# Understanding Repository Objects, do all start a new connection to the DB?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-2, ado.net, entity-framework-4

I have my **Database**, that have my **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** that have my **Repository** in one Application Library project

then, in the website for each **Controller** I start with

```
MyRepository db = new MyRepository();
```

I am expecting that this website will be accessed 50.000 a day and I was wondering... does the `new MyRepository()` part start a new **connection to the Database**?

is this safer?

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyRepository db { get; set; }

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (db == null) { db = new MyRepository(); }

        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
    ...
```

How can I learn a little bit more about how does the Entity Model hooks up into the database to **prevent** multiple **"bad" things to happen**?

I have several objects that I would **like to Cache it**, as they are pretty complex and never change (unless someone on the ADMIN area changes it), **what are my best options**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO.NET uses a [connection pool](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/02/09/connpool.html) which avoids creating connections to the database everytime. A pool of connections is created per application domain and per connection string and connections from this pool are reused. So when you instantiate your repository no connection is created to the database. For caching objects you might take a look at the [standard techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx).

As far as your example is concerned if `MyRepository` is disposable it is recommended to call the `Dispose` method on it which could be done in the `Dispose` method of the controller.

Comment: Should I inherit the IDisposable interface on `MyRepository` or I can simply use it as a normal object (`public class MyRepository {}`)?